# UIAlertView handle textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, alertview

i want to do a simple alertView and ask for the phone number...

```
   UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"What is your phone number?"
                                                      message:nil
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];

    message.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField* answerField = [message textFieldAtIndex:0];
    answerField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    answerField.placeholder = @"+43 ...";

    [message show];
```

And what do i have to put here into to check up something with the number (Like Mysql, etc.)

```
   - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {

UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

    ?????????
    // Something like  if (textField == "090012345678") -> NSLog(@"WOW"); ...

   }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know how to compare if two strings are the same then may I recommend that you seek out some basic tutorials on Objective-C.

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"090012345678"]) {
    NSLog(@"WOW");
}
```